# Command "python --verson" using "awk" extract version number

Tags: python, bash, awk, stderr

I know following command can show version of python

```sh
$ python --version
```

Result:

```
Python 3.7.4
```

I want to extract `3.7.4` only.

So, I attempt to following command using `awk`

```
$ python --version | awk '{print $2}'
```

But result still same as command `python --version` :

```
Python 3.7.4
```

I also try to specify delimiter space:

```
$ python --version | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
```

Result still same as `python --version`  :

```
Python 3.7.4
```

How do I do?

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl 's reply. But I've read link which you provide, but I don't understand those link relationship with my question.

Comment: did this command work for you?
echo `python --version` | awk '{print $2}'
what is your bash version?
bash --version

Comment: Following answer is already showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason is that python prints the output on stderr rather than stdout.
Solution e.g.:

```
python --version 2>&1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 python -c 'import platform; print(platform.python_version())'
```

Output (e.g.):

```
2.7.1
```